# Pandas: Group weighted average, how to control the name of the output column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a custom function for a weighted average.

Like,

`df.groupby(['group1', 'group2']).apply(weighted_average, 'val', 'wt')`

The returning series is something like,

```
group1                group2
foo                   a              8.085493
                      b             45.610411
                      c            161.959249
                      d             85.923614
                      e             30.953251
Abar                  a             24.000000
                      b             11.000000
                      c             18.723185
```

However, the weighted average column has no name. How do I explicitly name this column?

I don't want to rely on the fact that the column is assigned the name `0` because that could cause failure down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using setup from [@user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203)'s answer, you can use **[reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)** with `name`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'c': [1,4,3,2,1,6]})
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).c.mean().reset_index(name='avg')
```

Output:

```
   a    b   avg
0   1   1   1
1   1   2   4
2   2   3   3
3   2   4   2
4   3   5   1
5   3   6   6
```

Comment: Did not know that series' `reset_index` let you name it, +1

Comment: Glad, it helped you. @user3483203

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) and `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'c': [1,4,3,2,1,6]})
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).c.mean()

a  b
1  1    1
   2    4
2  3    3
   4    2
3  5    1
   6    6
```

Using `rename`

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).c.mean().rename('hello').reset_index()

   a  b  hello
0  1  1      1
1  1  2      4
2  2  3      3
3  2  4      2
4  3  5      1
5  3  6      6
```